# Error: "Sorry, this content could not be embedded" when using the Embed block

Tags: permalinks, block-editor

When trying to embed a URL to another post on my site, I received the "Sorry, this content could not be embedded." I had never had a problem before and always ended up with a nice preview image of the linked post, etc. But for some unknown reason, this one link returned an error.

Almost 99% of the answers on the interwebs were related to YouTube videos. However, this was a link to a post.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: turned out the link was a redirect. After the original post was published, I changed the title, and then Yoast created a redirect. So the solution was to embed the permalink of the destination post and not the original permalink.